# Getting userdata from codeigniter session which has been stored in DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I just enabled saving sessions in DB:

```
$login_info=array('logged_in_user_id' => $user_result['u_id'],
'logged_in_username'=> $user_result['u_username']);

$this->session->set_userdata('login',$login_info);
```

But I have problem with this code:

```
if(!empty($this -> session -> userdata('login')))
{
    echo "login true";
} else {
    echo "login false"; // I always get this one! 
        }
```

according to my above explanation:

1. Is it a secure way for manipulating login process in codeigniter?
2. What should I do to get the db session data and get rid of the
       problem above?

Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem you are facing with this code. ?

Comment: As I comment the code it always gives me FALSE and userdata is not set in the session... I just test that my `$user_result['u_id']` is not set in the session.. I don't know why?

Comment: please turn on profiler by inserting this line anywhere in code `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` now load the page and scroll down you will see bunch of debug data, use it to find out what the problem is. See section with "session". If its not there you are doing something wrong I guess saving. Also try out `var_dump($this->session->userdata('login'))`, what is output of that? I guess you should not check session with `empty()`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I fix this problem in other way, I see the data as you say in profile enable.. I didn't pass array for the session.. I put 2 separate values and it fixes. thanks! :)